# asyncio 'The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument'

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

Recently I've been trying to figure out async processing in Python but can't seem to wrap my head around the way it's structured. I'm used to the system Java has implemented where you can basically do whatever you want with runnables and it just works.

Basically, I want to make an application that runs both Flask and another websocket server at the same time and using Flask as a control panel for the server and the active connections (sort of like a dashboard). I managed to get the two processes running but now need to call an async function directly but can't seem to do so.

I have a controller class handling incoming connections like so:

```
class SessionController:
    app_controller = None
    app = None
    sessions = dict()

    def __init__(self, app_controller: 'AppController'):
        self.app_controller = app_controller

    async def start(self):
        self.app = await websockets.serve(
            self.connect,
            '0.0.0.0',
            8887,
            subprotocols=[Subprotocol('ocpp1.6')]
        )
        await self.app.wait_closed()

    async def connect(self, websocket, path):
        point_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        cp = Session(point_id, websocket)
        try:
            self.register(cp)
            await cp.start()
        except ConnectionClosedError:
            print("Connection reset")
        finally:
            self.unregister(cp)

    def register(self, cp):
        print("Client {0}:{1}#{2} connected".format(cp.websocket.host, cp.websocket.port, cp.point_id))
        self.sessions[cp.charge_point_id] = cp

    def unregister(self, cp):
        print("Client {0}:{1}#{2} disconnected".format(cp.websocket.host, cp.websocket.port, cp.point_id))
        self.sessions.pop(cp.point_id)

    def end_session(self, point_id):
        cp = self.sessions.get(point_id)
        cp.close()
        self.unregister(cp)
```

Now, when I get a connection it works fine, the session is created and registered in the sessions map. But when I try to call end_session with the ID of an active session I get the error `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketCommonProtocol.close' was never awaited self.websocket.close()`. The code still works and runs correctly, but preferably I wouldn't get an error, of course.

After doing some searching online people recommended that I tried asyncio and use a loop to run the method. I did this using the following code:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(self.websocket.close())
```

This gives me the following error though: `The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument`

I just cannot grasp the way python handles async, is there a way for me to call the function without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to run a webserver and also serve websockets, you rather use an ASGI server such as FastAPI (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

Note also that Flask is a WSGI server and will handle every request in a separate thread. If you are using an event-loop, the event-loop is local to the thread. Thus be careful when combining multi-threading and event-loops.

I can not exactly pinpoint your issue as your code sample does not include the Session class.

Comment: The session class doesn't really hold much it's basically just a data object holding the id and websocket at the moment. The class only has the close method which redirects to the websockets.close method as seen in the last code block

Comment: well, the reason you get `The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument` is exactly because the request to end the session is handled by a different thread than the request that created the session. Doing websockets using a WSGI framework is not straightforward. You might for instance use https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or ideally go an ASGI framework (such as FastAPI)

Comment: Based on this comment I figured out I could store the loop from the original websocket thread and call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(cp.close(), self.loop)`. It's probably not the cleanest solution but it works without having to overthrow the entire code. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I am happy it helped you. But if you want to stick with flask I would nevertheless recommend to create an extra thread in your flask app and have thread dedicated to running a loop. And then in every request you handle you can exchange data between the thread that is handling your request and the thread that is running the loop using the usual mechanisms (mutex, event, ...).

Comment: That might be good to do, I looked into the other systems but since the project I'm working on is already pretty far in development I can't really go back to any other library. Using a separate thread might be enough to do the trick though!